# CKEDITOR - delete a tag in a filter

Tags: ckeditor

For this sample markup:

```
<p>Hello <span class='blah'>John</span>, how are you?</p>
```

I am trying to create a filter that detects the blah class and leaves just the name John, removing the span. Here is my filter:

```
    var rules = {
        elements: {
            span: function(element) {
                if (element.hasClass("blah")) {
                    var text = element.children[0].value;
                    return text;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is my sample code to call this:

```
    var filter = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter(rules);
    var fragment = CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml(text);
    var writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter();
    filter.applyTo(fragment);
    fragment.writeHtml(writer);
    var results = writer.getHtml();
    console.log(results);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/RKPYw/83/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you would need to return an instance of `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text` instead of returning a string. But there's an easier way:

```
var rules = {
    elements: {
        span: function(element) {
            if (element.hasClass("blah")) {
                delete element.name;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Voila! The `<span>` tag was stripped, but its content was left.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the trick is to set both the name and the class attribute to an empty string. Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKPYw/84/). Here is the filter:

```
var filter = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter({
    elements: {
        span: function(element) {
            if (element.hasClass("blah")) {
                element.name = "";
                element.attributes.class = "";
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code will work, though it contains 2 unnecessary lines :). See my answer.